# Prop value doesn't pass to child component, can't figure out why

Tags: vue.js, vue-props

In my parent component I'm calling my child compoment "DotsNavigation" this way:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <dots-navigation :steps="steps" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import DotsNavigation from "@/components/dashboard/dots-navigation"

export default {
  components: {
    DotsNavigation
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      steps: [
        {
          title: "title1",
          path: "path1"
        },
        {
          title: "title2",
          path: "path2"
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And my child component "DotsNavigation" looks like this:

```
<template>
  <nav>
  <div v-for="(step, key) in steps">
    <router-link
      :key="`dot-${key}`"
      :to="`/dashboard/${step.path}`"
    >
      <div>
        {{ key + 1 }}
      </div>
      <div>
        {{ step.title }}
      </div>
    </router-link>
    <div
      :key="`line-${key}`"
      v-if="key !== steps.length - 1"
    ></div>
  </div>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    steps: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => []
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

In my child compoment, "steps" is empty. I can't figure out why this is so. Any idea?

Comment: does the consoles say anything? do you have the vue debugger browser tool? what is in the `...` in DotsNavigation?

Comment: how do you know it's empty? your code seems right

Comment: No console error. `steps` is empty, I see it in Vue chrome tool yes. I added the rest of the code that I had hidden with `...`

Comment: It could be a build or hot reload issue. Did you try manually restarting your build/dev process?

Comment: I wish it was, just rebuilt it and same issue :|

Comment: Your DotsNavigation component has multiple root components. You should wrap the  v-for div

Comment: @roliroli I agree with you.

Comment: Sorry I remove the top <nav> element to make my code as short as possible, it's a bad habit I have because sometimes I introduce new problems by doing so, sorry about that. Adding it back now. So, no that's not the issue either

Comment: I've added two of your components into existing test project fixed the issues that we have discussed above and now  it returns data and works. The data isn't `undefined`

Comment: add `key` to your `v-for` element

Comment: it works fine for me, maybe upload your entire codebase.

Comment: A few things you might try to debug the problem. 1. Try changing the `default` value of the `steps` prop so that it has something in it. This will help to narrow down where the emptiness is coming from. 2. Try adding `{{ steps }}` to the parent component's template. 3. Add some console logging to check the value of `steps`. The `created` or `mounted` hooks of either component would be good candidate locations. I suggest also logging the length or using `JSON.stringify`, in case the array is being changed before you access it in the console.

Comment: @skirtle your point #2 made me realise that my child component is called a different places in my app by different parent components. I was testing it with the wrong parent component... Quite embarrassing actually. But thank you very much for making me ask myself the right question!

Answer (score 0):

Try not using `template` element in `template`.
In your `DotsNavigation` replace inner `template` with `div` and see if it works:

```
<template>
  <nav>
    <div v-for="(step, key) in steps" :key="`div-${key}`">
        <router-link
      :key="`dot-${key}`"
      :to="`/dashboard/${step.path}`"
    >
      <div>
        {{ key + 1 }}
      </div>
      <div>
        {{ step.title }}
      </div>
    </router-link>
    <div
      :key="`line-${key}`"
      v-if="key !== steps.length - 1"
    ></div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks, nope it wasn't that

Comment: But there should be only one 'template' element anyway so you seem to have multiple errors there

Comment: @drake035 I changed the code. try this new one. It has to work now.

Comment: @drake035 I saw your new post. Try to add `key` to your `div` which has `v-for`